# Drupal 6 Triggered Rules and Rulesets

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-rules

I'm trying to create a rule/ruleset that:

- Is triggered when a user registered with the site
- Then (depending on a CCK field value included in the registration) add that user to a role
- Then redirect the user to a profile page.

I've tried no end of times and simply can't get it to work. 
I can create a triggered rule which fires upon registration (but doesn't allow me to perform all actions needed), nor does it allow me to select the ruleset with all the actions needed using rules schedular. 
One of the reasons I'm not allowed to select the ruleset under a triggered rule is the "arguments are not passed".

Any help is really appreciated or perhaps another way of achieving what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna guess that you are probably using content the module content profile to use CCK content types for user profiles, and that you have the content profile fields visible in the registration form. your problem is that you need to load the profile to be able to access values in the fields there.

Your best bet is to use http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole to handle the role assignment and then, use a rule to set the content profile field (if you really need to set that) once the user logs in.